# Moduli of finite-dimensional algebras

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $n\geq 1$ be an integer. There is an obvious family of $n$-dimensional unital algebras parametrized by $\mathbb{C}^{n(n-1)^2}$ such that any $n$-dimensional unital algebra is isomorphic to at least one algebra in the family.

A closed (possibly reducible) subvariety $V\subset \mathbb{C}^{n(n-1)^2}$ is representative if any $n$-dimensional commutative associative unital algebra is isomorphic to at least one algebra in the corresponding subfamily.

For $n\leq 6$ there is a zero-dimensional representative subvariety. What can we say about the minimum dimension of a representative subvariety for $n\geq 7$?

Comment: I don’t understand your second paragraph but see: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608491

Comment: see also [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/371150/14094) and comments there. In particular, if $m_n$ is this minimal dimension, then $\liminf m_n/n^3>0$ (with an explicit lower bound I'm just lazy to retrieve).